# AddInParameter and NULL?

Tags: c#, dbcommand

I have problems inserting a null paramater with the AddInParameter method.

```
cmd.AddInParameter(someString, someValueWhichCanBeNULL)
```

As soon as the 2nd param is null, it fails. I also Tried DBNull.Value, fails too. Ideas?

The message is: **AddInParameter @MyParam with null value** or **Unsupported Property Type: DBNull**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overload of `AddInParameter` that takes three arguments; you want this:

```
cmd.AddInParameter(someString, DbType.String, someValueWhichCanBeNULL);
```

(It can't determine the type of the parameter from the DBNull.Value alone)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Its not always a string...is that a problem?

Comment: Each parameter must be of a consistent, set type: so you should use the `DbType` most appropriate.  It doesn't need to be `String`, but it needs to be something, and that should match the type of parameter you are setting the value of.